# C++ problematic function, Array to List

Tags: c++, arrays, list, move, tolist

I have this code from programing class:

```
void ToList(List *first, int *arr, int n) {
    List *p = first;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       p->x = arr[i];
       if (p->next != NULL) p = p->next;
    }
}
```

I call it in order to transfer an Array element to a List:

```
int main() {

const int N = 10;
int m[N] = {5, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 9, 4, 0, 3};

List *first = NULL;

ToList(first, m, N);
PrintList(first);
```

I got a "Segmentation fault" -- the program finished with exit code 139. What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your list (`first`) is `NULL`, and you never allocated any memory for it

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Your functions expects all the list nodes to be allocated already. But you're passing an empty list to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you dereference a `NULL` pointer:

In `main`:

```
List *first = NULL;
```

In `ToList`:

```
List *p = first; // first = NULL
...
p->x = arr[i]
```

So, you need to allocate the list firstly.